# Attaching to and manipulating another program?

Tags: c++

Let me try to explain, its a bit difficult. I want to create a bot that will play single player Terraria, although the game itself is irrelevant.
I need to be able to do a couple things, I'll just make a list

1. Attach to the game
2. Send out movement and action commands (use item, etc)
3. Figure out constants and monitor variables. I need things such as movement mechanics, block breaking times, and life/mana in order for the bot to appropriately react to external stimulus. I want the bot to figure these things out on its own so that it can adapt to other environments, so feeding them in from the wiki won't help.

I believe I can figure out the rest, but I really don't even know where to start with these few things. To clarify, I'm not looking to copy and paste; I'd like to learn how to program this stuff but I have no clue where to look.

Some additional details, I'm a novice with C++. I've been poking around and assembly language has come up a couple times, and I wouldn't mind learning it or any other languages if its necessary. Sorry if the tag is inaccurate.

Comment: Before embarking on such an epic adventure, have you written a console program that plays tic-tac-toe?

Comment: Yes, I have a minimalist 2D game in SDL. I was hoping I could launch a demo on that and then move to another game, but it seems like it's not worth the effort to create an environment when some already exist.

Comment: If the game doesn't already have an API to access, then basically you're gonna have to hack the client somehow to get at the in-game variables. However, game clients are generally designed to prevent this. If it's a network game maybe you could sniff the network. As a last resort you could tap into the frame buffer and read stuff as seen on the screen, but then you're getting into deep waters.

Comment: Any resources on how to get in to the frame buffer? I think that would be the most adaptable approach.

Comment: @GDBobby There's no portable way unfortunately, it depends on the hardware etc. The frame buffer is generally located in ram on your video-card, so you'll need vendor-specific calls for that. Sometimes the OS provide an API for capturing the screen in a given process, _e.g._, https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/33297e25-d8f7-482c-9de5-ececeb297bb1/how-do-i-capture-a-screenshot-of-a-processs-main-window?forum=csharpgeneral

Comment: @GDBobby Interpreting images from a moving game is very difficult. Proper image-recognition tech is post-grad stuff and takes years to learn.

Comment: If you just want to play a game specifically with very predictable actions, try reading only a tiny patch of the screen and make do with that. To start with this, I'd suggest tetris.